# Pass icon button as props using react

Tags: reactjs

I have a common grid component where I define the structure of the grid and also structure of a button bar that goes on top of the grid.

Common-grid.js

```
 <Box height='100%' width='100%' position='absolute'>
                <div className="common-grid">
                    <div className="button-bar">
                    </div> 
                <div className="ag-grid">
                </div>
                </div>
    </Box>
```

I pass data to the grid from my other component based to fill in the grid.
MyComponent.js

```
{gridData.length > 0 && <Grid tableData={gridData} columnData={activeListColumnDef} {...props}/>}
```

Along with the data, I would also like to pass icon buttons that I would like to see in button bar.

```
<IconButton
  icon={<AddIcon />}
  onClick={onClickOpenActiveListEditor}
 />
 <IconButton
  icon={<EditIcon />}
 />
```

I do not want to define icon buttons in the common component but pass it as props. Is it possible to pass such html elements along with its event listeners as props?  Please help!

Comment: why not import the icon inside the component instead passing it?

Comment: Because I would be using common grid from multiple components. And every component will have its own set of icons to be displayed in button bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's called a render prop. Just directly pass the node like this:

```js
// in the parent component
<Grid 
  tableData={gridData} 
   columnData={activeListColumnDef} 
   icon={<AddIcon onClick={onClickOpenActiveListEditor} />}
   {...props}
 />


// in the Grid component
function Grid({tableData, columnData, icon}){
  return (
    <>
    // grid stuff
    {icon && icon}
    </>
  )
}
```

If you need typescript support, the node would typed as such:

```js
interface GridProps{
  // stuff
  icon?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Comment: If I pass a div element that has multiple icons as props instead of just <addIcon/>. Will that still be okay ?

Comment: You can pass anything you want as a render prop as long as it is a valid dom node (so wrapped in a single html element). Usually, render props are used to avoid handling edgecases in a component. Indeed, you don't want to pass props such as isDisabled, onIconClick, etc. and have a mess in your final component. The idea is to keep things clean by allowing potential messy elements as a simple node. hence the `{icon && icon}`. part written above.

Comment: If this answer suits you, please mark it as valid so other people can benefit from a resolved thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
const renderIcon = (onClick) => { 
  return <Icon onClick={onClick} />
}

...


<IconButton renderIcon={renderIcon} />
```

Then, inside `IconButton`:

```
{renderIcon()}
```